# Should I change from a MariaDB to Splunk or use a Splunk DBX connection?

Tags: database, splunk

### Problem

Currently, I have my data in a MariaDB and there has been a recent push in my group to move things to Splunk. Everyone in my group is a DB novice, we can push things and pull them out but as far as making smart decisions on which kind of DB to use, it's the blind leading the blind. The biggest draw of Splunk is the ease of creating "dashboards" that could help us to use the data more effectively. I'm trying to understand the best choice between switching everything into Splunk or just using the Splunk DBX thing to get the benefits of the easy dashboards and keep the MariaDB the same.

### My Data

There are 2 separate databases that do different things but they are set up almost identically so I'll just talk about one of them and when I talk about the amount of traffic I'll use the numbers from the one with the most traffic.

There is 1 table that contains a list of tools and information on those tools.

There are 3 other tables that log the usages of those tools using a foreign key(I think!) to point to the tools table and it tracks by user per week. There are 3 different tables because there are 3 different tool types that I track different kinds of information. But they have a similar setup to this one.

Example:

| id | tool_id | user | week | usages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | Joe | w5 | 5 |
| 4 | 5 | Joe | w6 | 3 |

Each time a tool is used I update the row by incrementing the usages column.

### Expected DB Traffic

Adding/Updating data happens sometimes thousands of times an hour, so far the in-house DBaaS has handled the traffic without a problem.

For querying, I do queries of essentially the entire DB maybe 10 times a day, if that, **BUT**, when a tool is used I query the tools table to figure out what usage tracking table to use, then do the add/update on the appropriate table.

### Limitations

I'm limited to MariaDB, PostgreSQL, and Splunk databases at this time. I have minimal Splunk experience and no PostgreSQL experience. I'm most experienced in MariaDB but that just means I can understand the documentation and follow it to make more elaborate queries.

### Questions

Should I stay with MariaDB and connect to Splunk for the easier querying and dashboard creations for more real time data and better analysis of the data **OR** move entirely to Splunk?

Is there another option I don't know about?

Please also feel free to offer any other advice you may have!

### Why Can't I Figure This Out Myself?

I've tried for several days now, but everything I can find is too vague with their descriptions. To me a DB that is ten-thousand rows long is large, but apparently a real DB expert would laugh at me for thinking that. So I can't tell if because of the size of my data maybe it doesn't even matter what I do or maybe it's extremely important.

Comment: It doesn't even matter what you do

Comment: Try maintaining your MariaDB and exploring connecting to Splunk, and see what happens.  Changing database engines is always a risky endeavor, with an unknown number of software changes.  You can start considering PostgreSQL when your tables get up to about 10 billion rows each.

Comment: @ysth is that because of the amount of data?

Answer (score 1):

Splunk is not a database so it won't replace MariaDB (or any other database program).  The main reason being data in Splunk is immutable so the DB concept of updating a row has no equivalent in Splunk.

Consider using Splunk's DB Connect plug-in to connect it to your MariaDB.  That gives Splunk the ability to pull data from the database so it can be analyzed and/or visualized.

Also consider other visualization tools like Tableau.

Comment: Someone suggested to me that we would simply log every usage as a separate entry then I can just count them up. Is that a reasonable strategy or should I stick with my current MariaDB strategy

Comment: Yes, that is a reasonable strategy.